# Firefox addon to open source file(s) in your favorite IDE

Tags: visual-studio, firebug, external

While developing a web application in Visual Studio, I want to be able to quickly open a source file (an xsl, a js, etc, not the "view source" result) in Visual Studio. My idea is to:

- Write out http response headers (in debug mode), identifying the local files (c:...\bla.aspx) that helped build up the response
- Read these http headers in FireBug to render them as clickable in a new tab
- Make these clickable urls launch a an IDE (configurable) with certain parameters

I am pretty sure that this can be achieved using a combination of http headers, firebug and launchy. But I was wondering if anyone knows of an existing/easier way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

For example Zend Studio toolbar.